# Is there a git repository for Drupal releases only?

Tags: version-control

Having cloned drupal from the git repository using

```
git clone --branch 7.x http://git.drupal.org/project/drupal.git
```

I noticed that I'm actually running 7.9-dev when what I want to be running is the most recent stable. Is there a git repository or branch that I can pull from to run the most recent stable release? I've seen references to git.drupal.org/project-stable/drupal.git around the net, but that doesn't seem to be a valid repository anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drupal releases are marked with a corresponding "tag" within the repository. When you clone a git repository, you get all the tags and branches along with it. Running the following command from within the repository will checkout the version 7.8 tag:

```
git checkout 7.8
```

To list the available tags, type `git tag`. To list all available branches, type `git branch -a`.

Comment: I didn't even think to look at the tags. (facepalm)